# Returning HTML (with PHP) after jQuery Ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax together with jQuery to make a little window pop up when you click on a username in my custom forums.

My current code for the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#profile_link').click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'viewuser.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            contentType: 'text/html',
            data: {
                username: $('#username').val()
            },
            success: function (html) {
                $('#message').addClass('success');
                $('#message').hide().append(html).fadeIn();
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

I tried using html(), but that didn't work at all, as it didn't even display the response, even though I could see the response in Firebug.

Here's the code to viewuser.php:

```
        <?php 
      $docRoot = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT");

      require_once $docRoot.'/settings.php';

      loginMySQL();

      selectDatabase();

      $user = $_POST['username'];

      $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT `UserName`,`Avatar`,`Biography`,`Birthday`,`UserLevel`,`BanStatus` FROM users WHERE `UserName` = '$user'");

      $UserInfo = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
       $UserAvatar = $UserInfo['Avatar'];
       $UserBio = $UserInfo['Biography'];
       $UserBirth = $UserInfo['Birthday'];
       $UserLevel = $UserInfo['UserLevel'];
       $BanStatus = $UserInfo['BanStatus'];

   // additional code
   ...
      ?>
      <div class="nav_space">
      </div>
// additional code
      <div class="user_profile_wrapper">
       Hello
       <?=$BanStatus;?>
       <i>Username / Power level:</i>
       <div class="user_profile_name" <?=$LevelColour;?>>
       <?=$user;?> <i><?=$UserLevel;?></i>
       </div>
       <i>User avatar:</i>
       <div class="user_profile_avatar">
      <?
       if (strlen($UserAvatar) > 1) {
       ?>
       <img/ src="<?=$UserAvatar;?>" alt="" width="100" />
       <?
       }
      ?>
       </div>
       <i>Biography:</i><br />
       <div class="user_profile_bio">
       <?=$UserBio;?>
       </div>
       <i>Birthdate:</i>
       <div class="user_profile_birthdate">
       <?=$UserBirth;?>
       </div>
       <?=$AUserLevel;?>
      </div>
      <div class="nav_space">
      </div>
```

And the problem is, when it returns the code, it doesn't actually display any of the variables ($BanStatus, $UserLevel, anything).

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to debug your PHP code to see why those variables aren't set. Calling the script directly and outputting the query and doing a `print_r($UserInfo)` might be a good start.

Comment: try using web development for JavaScript errors.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/
Try just sending 'hello world' from php script...

Comment: Also try using doctrine or some other ORM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you shouldn't change between `<?php` and `<?` as I believe support for short tags is being dropped.

Also, you haven't sanitised your user name

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string  ($_POST['username']);
```

**Updated 1**

The code below is a working example, I have cleaned up your code a little bit. However with your original code changing `username : $('#username').val()`
 to `username : $('#username').html()` should work for you.

Code for so.html

```
  <a href="www.google.com" id="profile_link"><div id="username">Someusername</div></a>

  <div id="message"></div>
<script>
  $("#profile_link").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var v_username = $("#username").html();
    $.post("viewuser.php",{"username": v_username},function(data) {
      $('#message').addClass('success').hide().html(data).fadeIn();
    }, "html");

  });
</script>
```

Code for viewuser.php

```
<?php
echo "The submitted request was for the username $_POST[username]";
?>
```

Output:

> The submitted request was for the username Someusername

**Updated 2**

Code for so.html

```
  <a href="www.google.com" class="profile_link"><span class="username">Username1</span></a>
    <a href="www.google.com" class="profile_link"><span class="username">Username2</span></a>

  <div id="message"></div>
<script>
  $(".profile_link").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var v_username = $(this).children(".username").html();
    $.post("viewuser.php",{"username": v_username},function(data) {
      $('#message').addClass('success').hide().html(data).fadeIn();
    }, "html");

  });
</script>
```

I've updated it once again for you. We use $(this).children(".username") to ensure that we return the username from the selected link. We've changed to to use classes as there are more than one instance of each element now, and I've changed the html to use a span tag as it's a bit more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for you response,
I've tried using the code you're written, but it doesn't even fade in with your code, that is, nothing happens.
With my code, all appears beside the variables.

Comment: I have found the error you should be using html() instead of val() I have changed my code to reflect this. All effects also work. If this works for you, don't forget to accept my answer/vote.

And PLEASE don't forget to sanitise your database search strings.

Comment: Ah, your solution works perfectly.
Thanks a lot for you help Jamie, would have up'ed your reputation, but I can't.
Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, I'm facing a little problem.
Since this works (for the moment) only at the place, where it says "Active users" in my forum (http://cf.zcrembo.com), there will obviously be more than 1 active user. Problem is, when you click on the second user, nothing happens. Any idea?

Comment: @Crembo - You are using ID selectors. IDs are meant to be unique - only one element in the whole page should have any ID, so if you have more than one user, and the HTML markup for those users means that both are `<span id="username">John Bloggs</span>` you will have problems. Try changing the ID attribute to a CLASS attribute (which does not need to be unique) and try that out. (NOTE: Whilst IDs are shown `#username` in jQuery, CLASSes are shown `.username`, so adjust the jQuery to match.)

Comment: Updated once again, we have to use the $(this) selector to ensure that we return the value of the link that is clicked. Hope this helps.
Accepted answer?

Comment: No problem. I'm quite impressed with myself actually. I've only dabbled with ajax once really. The jquery docs are really handy too!